# how to keep some items left and some items right in bootstrap nav bar?

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am a beginner in bootstrap have just studied yesterday.In this [bootply](http://bootply.com/112091) home,link,more,options are in the left side.I want to keep home at right top side of the screen so I used [class pull-right](http://bootply.com/112092) but its not working

Comment: Please post your code that you have tried so far.

Comment: @LearnerStudent I have posted the link so I did not post the code again.If its required to post the codes also then I will post.As I said I tried with pull-right class and This code is available in the 2nd link.Please tell me shall I post the code again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply in this way :

```
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="navbar-header"><a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a></div>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
       <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">More</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Options</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right">
       <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Wow great,Its working,+1.I will accept answer after 3 minutes